# How can this function be the connecting homomorphism of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence if it's not composed of the same functions?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**:

> Assume $X = X_1^{\circ} \cup X_2^{\circ}$.  If $D: H_n(X) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(X_1 \cap X_2)$ is the connecting homomorphism in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, then $D(\text{cls }z) = D(\text{cls }(\gamma_1 + \gamma_2)) = \text{cls } \partial \gamma_1 $.

Proof:

> Define $h_{\text{#}} : S_n(X_1) / S_n(X_1 \cap X_2) \rightarrow S_n(X) + S_n(X_2) / S_n(X_2)$ and $q_{\text{#}} : S_n(X) \rightarrow S_n(X) + S_n(X_2) / S_n(X_2)$, where $q_{\text{#}} : \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 \mapsto \gamma_1 + S_n(X_2)$ and $H_{\text{#}}$ is the isomorphism of the second isomorphism theorem.  Hence $h_{\text{#}}^{-1}$ sends the coset $\gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + S_n(X)$ to $\gamma_1 + S_n(X_1 \cap X_2)$.

The author then states:

> The formula for $D$ for the connecting homomorphism of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is $D = d{h_{\text{#}}^{-1}} q_{\text{#}}$, where $d$ is the connecting homomorphism from the exact sequence: $0 \rightarrow S_*(X_1 \cap X_2) \rightarrow S_*(X_1) \rightarrow S_*(X_1) / S_*(X_1 \cap X_2) \rightarrow 0$.

This problem with this is that he defined $D$ as the connecting homomorphism of the Mayer Vietoris sequence by $D = d' h_*^{'-1}q_*'$, where $d'$ is the connecting homomorphism of the pair $(X_1, X_1 \cap X_2)$, and $h_*^{'-1} : H_n(X, X_2) \rightarrow H_n(X_1, X_1 \cap X_2)$ and $q_*' : H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(X, X_2)$.

But $h \neq h'$ and $q \neq q'$ and $d \neq d'$.  The rest of the proof makes sense if we just let $D$ be the function defined above but I don't see it's relationship to the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.  $q$ and $h$ have the same domains as $q'$ and $h'$, respectively, but their comdomains are not equal:  $S_n(X_1) + S_n(X_2) / S_n(X_2) \neq S_n(X) / S_n(X_2)$.

Is there a relationship between $S_n(X_1) + S_n(X_2) / S_n(X_2) $ and $ S_n(X) / S_n(X_2)$ that I'm missing or does this theorem have nothing to do with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Comment: What does $\text{cls}$ mean?

Comment: $\text{cls z } \in H_n(X)$ means $z + B_n(X)$, where $z \in Z_n(X) = \text{ker } \partial_n$ and $B_n(X) = \text{im}(\partial_{n+1})$ such that $\partial_k : S_k(X) \rightarrow S_{k-1}(X)$.

Comment: So cls z is the homology class of the cycle $z$.